# How to read doubles out of a scanner and put them into an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, double, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner data = new Scanner("2.30 4.50 10.35 200.61 82.00");
ArrayList<Double> test = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

This is what I have, I do not need to take input from the mouse but I *have* to use a scanner to put my values in. I am testing a class that retrieves and stores data from and to an array list but I need to first get the values in the scanner into the list.

```
while(data.hasNextDouble()) {
    testUno.add(data.nextDouble()); 
}
```

I tried doing something like this afterwards but it did not work.

Comment: My advice: post the code you have (all relevant part of it) explain what you want and what didn't work

Comment: If you provide input to your app using stdin, then Scanner should be created as new Scanner(System.in)

Comment: It should work correctly. As @RC. stated, provide us with more code because the scanner isn't the problem.

Comment: You've declared your ArrayList as test but in the while loop you refer to it as testUno

Comment: @Brunaldo Makes sense

Comment: Unless you can absolutely guarantee that the inputs will always be strings of characters that represent legitimate doubles (what if it contains "2.30 4.T0 10.35"), you might be better off using a loop to read the inputs, with each read inside a try-catch block, or at least using hasNextDouble() before trying to read the next token as a double..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set explicitly a `Locale` that uses a **dot as decimal separator** (like in your input values) otherwise if your default Locale uses for example a comma as separator your values won't be seen as `double` by the `Scanner` such that `hasNextDouble()` will return `false`, use [`Scanner#useLocale(locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale-java.util.Locale-) for this purpose as next:

```
Scanner data = new Scanner("2.30 4.50 10.35 200.61 82.00");
// Set the locale to US as it is a locale that uses a dot as decimal separator
data.useLocale(Locale.US);
List<Double> testUno = new ArrayList<>();
while(data.hasNextDouble()) {
    testUno.add(data.nextDouble());
}
System.out.println(testUno);
```

**Output:**

```
[2.3, 4.5, 10.35, 200.61, 82.0]
```

> *Scanner#useLocale(Locale locale)* 
>    Sets this scanner's locale to the
>   specified locale. A scanner's locale **affects many elements of its
>   default primitive matching regular expressions**; see [localized numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers).